# Specification of distances for calculation of marked variogram

Tags: spatstat

In the spatstat package, why doesn't the markvario function allow distances greater than 1/4 of the window length for variogram calculation?

markvario(X, correction = c("isotropic", "Ripley", "translate"),
r = NULL, method = "density", ..., normalise=FALSE)

The argument r is a numeric vector. The values of the argument r at which the mark variogram gamma(r) should be evaluated.

The window length for the spruces dataset is 200m, but the variogram plot shows distances until 50m only, even specificating r to [0, 200].

> plot(markvario(longleaf,r=seq(0,200, by=0.5)))
>   [marked variogram for spruces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFKPy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `markvario` returns an object of class `fv` (function values).
It’s effectively a `data.frame` with additional attributes. One attribute
tells the `plot` command (dispatched to `plot.fv`) the recommended plotting
range. If you look at the bottom of the printed output you will see that `r`
runs from 0 to 200 but the recommended range is 0 to 50. You override the
default with the `xlim` argument:

```r
library(spatstat)
rslt <- markvario(longleaf,r=seq(0,200, by=0.5))
rslt
#> Function value object (class 'fv')
#> for the function r -> gamma(r)
#> ...........................................................................
#>       Math.label               
#> r     r                        
#> theo  {gamma[]^{iid}}(r)       
#> trans {hat(gamma)[]^{trans}}(r)
#> iso   {hat(gamma)[]^{iso}}(r)  
#>       Description                                       
#> r     distance argument r                               
#> theo  theoretical value (independent marks) for gamma(r)
#> trans translation-corrected estimate of gamma(r)        
#> iso   Ripley isotropic correction estimate of gamma(r)  
#> ...........................................................................
#> Default plot formula:  .~r
#> where "." stands for 'iso', 'trans', 'theo'
#> Recommended range of argument r: [0, 50]
#> Available range of argument r: [0, 200]
#> Unit of length: 1 metre
plot(rslt, xlim = c(0, 200))
```

[image]

Comment: Good to hear. If you like, you can go ahead and accept the answer so it doesn't appear as unsolved for future readers.